# PCM audio to Char Array for use in Android NDK

Tags: android, c, audio, android-ndk, low-latency

I'm trying to create a low latency audio application on Android and I've run into some issues.

I've attempted using AssetManager to play WAV (PCM encoded) files through OpenSl ES on 4.2+ but have found that it isn't quite up to scratch with what I require.

From the Native-Audio sample found in the NDK, I'm trying to create a BufferQueue to play buffered char array's of my clips.

My problem lies in the fact I'm not sure how to create these char arrays as they have done in the example, such as "hello_clip.h" which I've included a sample of below:

```
"\x00\x00\xfd\xff\x01\x00\x01\x00\xf9\xff\xfb\xff\x02\x00\x05\x00"
"\x01\x00\x03\x00\x06\x00\x0a\x00\x0a\x00\x09\x00\x04\x00\x04\x00"
"\x06\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x05\x00\x08\x00\x01\x00\xfe\xff"
"\xff\xff\x03\x00\x04\x00\xfe\xff\xf9\xff\xfd\xff\x04\x00\xfe\xff"
"\x03\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\xfb\xff\xfb\xff\xfc\xff\xfb\xff\x03\x00"
"\xfc\xff\xf9\xff\xfc\xff\x01\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\xf9\xff\xfa\xff"
"\x04\x00\x06\x00\xfe\xff\xfa\xff\xfd\xff\x01\x00\xfe\xff\xfe\xff"
"\xfe\xff\xfd\xff\xfd\xff\xfd\xff\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xfd\xff\xfa\xff"
"\xfe\xff\x00\x00\x03\x00\xfe\xff\xfc\xff\xfb\xff\xfe\xff...
```

It's then proceeded to be included in the project as such:

```
static const char hello[] =
    #include "hello_clip.h"
;
```

How can I possibly generate a similar char array file from PCM audio to use as a char array?

My experience with C and NDK is limited, and I've found the documentation and examples for OpenSl ES on android to not be very helpful. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try googling for "bin2h"

Comment: On Linux, `xxd -include` works too.  Of course, loading the clip from an asset is probably better than hard-coding it into the application binary.

Comment: What fadden said. This is exactly what xxd (available on all unix) is used for.

Comment: Nor is it hard to use C standard-library APIs to open files on the device's filing system (the location of which you've passed from Java over JNI).